# How to make aware co worker about their parking skills?

Tags: conflict-aversion, work-environment, politeness, united-kingdom, coworkers

I work in a MNC (Multi national company) in a populated city where having a car is necessary for transport purposes and daily commute.

### **Question**

**How can I tell/make aware a coworker (who is not in my team or department) about their parking skills?**

I have been working for this company for over couple of years. Parking is free where I work - courtesy of my workplace. However there are limited spaces, almost as many spaces as number of vehicles.
This co-worker of mine has terrible parking skills and uses 2 spaces everyday.

I have tried to illustrate the parking section where we are allowed to park.
[image: parking description of the issue]

**My problem**

My working hours are usually based on traffic and due to which I pop in late in mornings. Therefore most parking spaces are taken and only the slot next to my coworker's car is still free. However, because of their poor driving skills, there's not room enough for me to park (please see illustration below)

NB. this person is not disabled, I made sure of that.

[image: Illustration of how said coworker park their car. It takes up two slots]

I have to circle twice to find a space or else park in section where someone has to ask me to move my car in case they want to leave (in front of the building).

**What I have tried so far**

1. I was having a light conversation with the receptionist downstairs once and I did mention to them about it, in case they can tell the car owner about it. I guess the receptionist wasn't aware of it as it's been a long time.
2. This person does not park do reverse park - Once or twice I tried reverse parking so close to his car's tail, as close as I can, so that he would struggle to take his car out and ask me to move my car (as described below). I'd have used that opportunity to talk him through nicely - hoping he'd understand.

[image: OP's idea of reverse parking to prevent their coworker to leave without having to talk to them first]

Unfortunately, his working hours seem to be longer than mine and I left early both times I tried this. Also this was a risky way, as there's a small chance of getting my car scratched.

**What I thought of doing but didn't**

1. **Leave a note on the car**. I have my reservations especially regarding this way: I personally find it rude to leave any note on any car. One might get aggressive and park in an even worse way.
2. **Confront this person.** We have shared places where all car registration numbers are shared amongst all employees. I know in which department this person works but never met him face to face. I do not usually get involved in such meters and I would want to use this as a last resort only.

How can I make aware my coworker that their way of parking prevents other people to use the slot next to theirs? I'd like to solve this issue in a non confrontational way.

Comment: Hi MBD! Welcome to IPS. This is not a duplicate, but I thought you might find this [related question](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/18091/how-to-try-to-get-my-neighbour-to-park-their-car-in-their-assigned-spot) interesting. It's about communicating with someone who parks in a disturbing way as well.

Comment: can you take a photo from an upstairs window ?

Comment: Just as an FYI : some people park that way on purpose to make sure no one can park beside them. Often these are people who love their car and are afraid someone with poor parking skills will scratch it. The fact that your colleague always park this way makes me think they might do it on purpose.

Comment: @bigbadmouse I wish I can but that might expose more details about myself / car.

Comment: @MlleMei It's seem reasonable, however doing that seem stupid at the same. :|

Comment: *I personally find it rude to leave any note on any car* - isn't a message written nicely instead of rude less embarrasing than getting told to park better in person or have superiors involved?

Answer (score 18):

I've had the same problem a few times. Especially in our condo. It's the same situation. And yes, you're right, anything done by yourself may lead to worse than good, I've seen it happen.

What to do then? Ask the one in charge to write (or send) a small note/reminder. NICE. Not accusative in any way. For instance :

> Hi everyone, as you all know, we have some troubles with our parking lots. It's really important that, when you park, you all make sure that your car is straight in its lot. Once in a while, it's been noticed that some room was wasted. And some of us having a hard time finding a free and easy to use place. Please make sure that your car does not "spill" on the next lane. 
>   We appreciate your cooperation. Thanks.

This is very impersonal, does not point finger to anyone, and shouldn't upset anyone. That's the best way I've witnessed when dealing with such a problem. Because sometimes, people just don't see they have bothered someone else, they realize, and are more careful.

Ask the people in charge in upper management to nicely take care of it.

Comment: Have seen this a few times in private parking lots: Please park prettily. Sometimes with a little diagram. If the parking area is surrounded by a wall they often add; Please don't park backwards because it marks the wall.

Comment: Very Interesting approach. but escalating to HR department might not be a best option as one day or another if this person finds out about it and might ask me why didn't I confront him first.

Comment: We had a similar situation with people who were leaving the toilets in a dreadful state, a stern email from upper management sorted things out nicely. No one ever found out who requested it be sent.

Comment: I think the person is unlikely to confront you because in order to do so they would have to admit that they are a bad parker that caused the notice to be sent out, and indicate that they were essentially planning to keep parking poorly until given a personal invitation to stop being rude. I don't think anyone would want to implicate themselves like that!